# Printing between association of a list and a table

Tags: python

Currently, i have a list and a table both containing:

```
data = [97,89,43]
table = [[1, 97],[2, 89],[3, 102],[4, 12],[5, 43]]
```

and i want to print the values in data together with the first column value associated in the table. Output:

```
1 : 97
2 : 89
5 : 43
```

I have attempted:

```
n = len(data)       #having some problems here
for k in range(n):      # loop 3 times
    for j in range(n):    # loop 3 times
        if table[j][1] == data[k]:
            print( str(table[j][0]+ ':' + " " + str(data[k]))
```

but the issue I'm facing now is that if i take

```
n = len(data)
```

the loop would only loop 3 times and it won't be able to loop further on until the rest of the elements in the table is scanned, giving me only:

```
 1 : 97
 2 : 89
 #error message, index out of range
```

What modification could i do in order to achieve the output desired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's look like @RomanPerekhrest has solved your problem, but I would like to add some comments on your code.

The problem is here

```
...
    for j in range(n):    # loop 3 times *You have to loop `len(data)` times here or you miss checking table[3], ...*
        if table[j][1] == data[k]:
            ...
```

`n` is 3 (`len(data)`, but what you need is 5 that is `len(table)`) here, thus the forth and later elements of `table` are not checked in the for loop.

A more pythonic way of your code should be

```
data = [97,89,43]
table = [[1, 97],[2, 89],[3, 102],[4, 12],[5, 43]]

for i in data:
    for j in table:
        if i == j[1]:
            print('{} : {}'.format(*j))
```

Answer (score 3):

With single `for` loop:

```
data = [97,89,43]
table = [[1, 97],[2, 89],[3, 102],[4, 12],[5, 43]]

for v1, v2 in table:
    if v2 in data:
        print('{} : {}'.format(v1, v2))
```

The output:

```
1 : 97
2 : 89
5 : 43
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [sub_value for value in data for sub_value in table if value in sub_value]
for value in data:
    col, row = value
    print('{col} : {row}'.format(col=col,row=row))
>>>   1 : 97
      2 : 89
      5 : 43
```